# SQL stored procedure for picking a random sample based on multiple criteria

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am new to SQL. I looked for all over the internet for a solution that matches the problem I have but I couldn't find any. I have a table named 'tblItemReviewItems' in an SQL server 2012.
[tblItemReviewItems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLTFc.png)

**Information**:
1. ItemReviewId column is the PK.
2. Deleted column will have only "Yes" and "No" value.
3. Audited column will have only "Yes" and "No" value.

I want to create a stored procedure to do the followings:

1. Pick a random sample of 10% of all ItemReviewId for distinct 'UserId' and distinct 'ReviewDate' in a given date range. **10% sample should include- 5% of the total population from Deleted (No) and 5% of the total population from Deleted (Yes).** Audited ="Yes" will be excluded from the sample.

For example – A user has 118 records. Out of the 118 records, 17 records have  Deleted column value "No" and 101 records have Deleted column value "Yes".  We need to pick a random sample of 12 records. Out of those 12 records, 6 should have **Deleted column value "No"** and 6 should have **Deleted column value "Yes"**.

2. Update Audited column value to "Check" for the picked sample.

How can I achieve this?

This is the stored procedure I used to pick a sample of 5% of Deleted column value "No" and 5% of Deleted column value "Yes". Now the situation is different.

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[spItemReviewQcPickSample]  
    (  
         @StartDate Datetime  
        ,@EndDate Datetime 
     )  
    AS  
    BEGIN  
    WITH CTE  
      AS (SELECT ItemReviewId  
                ,100.0  
                *row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY UserId  
                                               ,ReviewDate  
                                               ,Deleted  
                                       order by newid()  
                                  )
                /count(*) OVER(PARTITION BY UserId  
                                           ,Reviewdate  
                                           ,Deleted  
                              )  
                 AS pct  
           FROM tblItemReviewItems  
           WHERE ReviewDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate  
             AND Deleted in ('Yes','No')  
             AND Audited='No'  
         )  
    SELECT a.*  
      FROM tblItemReviewItems AS a  
           INNER JOIN cte AS b  
                   ON b.ItemReviewId=a.ItemReviewId  
                  AND b.pct<=6  
    ;  
    WITH CTE  
      AS (SELECT ItemReviewId  
                ,100.00  
                *row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY UserId  
                                               ,ReviewDate  
                                               ,Deleted  
                                       ORDER BY newid()  
                                  )
                /COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY UserId  
                                           ,Reviewdate  
                                           ,Deleted  
                              )  
                 AS pct  
            FROM tblItemReviewItems  
           WHERE ReviewDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate  
             AND deleted IN ('Yes','No')  
             AND audited='No'  
         )  
    UPDATE a  
       SET Audited='Check'  
      FROM tblItemReviewItems AS a  
           INNER JOIN cte AS b  
                   ON b.ItemReviewId=a.ItemReviewId  
                  AND b.pct<=6  
    ;  
    END
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This may assist you in getting started. My idea is, you create the temp tables you need, and load the specific data into the (deleted, not deleted etc.). You then run something along the lines of:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpTest') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpTest
GO
CREATE TABLE #tmpTest
(
    ID  INT                 ,
    Random_Order INT
)

INSERT INTO #tmpTest
(
    ID
)
SELECT 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 4 UNION ALL
SELECT 5 UNION ALL
SELECT 6 UNION ALL
SELECT 7 UNION ALL
SELECT 8 UNION ALL
SELECT 9 UNION ALL
SELECT 10 UNION ALL
SELECT 11 UNION ALL
SELECT 12 UNION ALL
SELECT 13 UNION ALL
SELECT 14 UNION ALL
SELECT 15 UNION ALL
SELECT 16;

DECLARE @intMinID   INT ,
        @intMaxID   INT;


SELECT  @intMinID = MIN(ID)
FROM    #tmpTest;

SELECT  @intMaxID = MAX(ID)
FROM    #tmpTest;

WHILE @intMinID <= @intMaxID

    BEGIN
        UPDATE  #tmpTest
        SET     Random_Order = 10 + CONVERT(INT, (30-10+1)*RAND())
        WHERE   ID = @intMinID;

        SELECT @intMinID = @intMinID + 1;
    END

SELECT      TOP 5 *
FROM        #tmpTest
ORDER BY    Random_Order;
```

This assigns a random number to a column, that you then use in conjunction with a TOP 5 clause, to get a random top 5 selection.

Appreciate a loop may not be efficient, but you may be able to update to a random number without it, and the same principle could be implemented. Hope that gives you some ideas.